# Is it possible to have an updateable log for an event?

Tags: civievent, 4.7, 4.6

We have a requirement where we want to have a user updateable 'log' (text area) attached to an event. A custom field is the obvious answer but the  screen to update the field (event config) would not be suitable as it exposes critical data. Webforms for events are oriented toward contact signups - not at the event level but at the contact level, so are not suitable. And profiles can't be used for events, can they? The event in question is a nightshelter, where we use a webform to sign in guests. We want the night staff to be able to use Civi to keep a log for the night (i.e. the event), but apart from adding a custom field to the event (as described above) there doesn't seem to be a usable solution for us. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What about using activities and a contact for the shelter?
Each activity would be an entry, you can use activity types, so it might make it easier to get some analysis on the log.

There isn't any direct link between the log and the event, but you can filter by date and get the activities linked to a specific event (night).

you could write an extension to change the layout of the event backoffice and provide a filtered view.

Comment: Thanks, Xavier - in fact one of our users created a contact and added a case to it, with activities as the log. You suggestion is more simple so that's what we might do. Working with small charities with no money I don't want to write code so this is probably the way to go but it's a shame there's no built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need custom code to do this.  Consider creating an event page that only exposes the name of the event and the custom field used for the log, using an ACL override on the custom page to allow people to edit the event who wouldn't ordinarily be able to.

Comment: Thanks, Jon as mentioned above this is what we'd do if we had the time & resources but was hoping there was a built-in way to do this, which there isn't.